# Session Variable Set in Global.asax, but coming back as null in MVC5 View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am setting a Session variable in my global.asax like so:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["HttpStatusCode"] = statusCode;
```

I am trying to retrieve it in a View like so:

```
@{
    if (Session["HttpStatusCode"] != null)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

I am always getting null when trying to use the Session variable in the View. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where in the Global.asax are you setting the session variable?  Depending on where you set it, session isn't available.

Comment: How is statusCode being populated?

Comment: @Fran I am setting it in Application_Error and when I check it while still in Application_Error it is still there. As soon as I try to use it in my View it is gone.

Comment: Can you include your whole Application_Error handler.  where is statusCode declared and set?  Do you know the call stack for the error?  Is this occurring in application startup?  in a controller action?  a better solution might be to create a custom HandleErrorAtrribute that can then forward information to a custom error view.